# Including some static html files?

Tags: gwt

Where can we place static html files in our war file? For example, a default project has this:

```
war/projectname.html
```

I'd like to just make a few static folders with static pages that are like:

```
war/projectname.html
war/signup/index.html
war/about/index.html
```

so that my users can just hit those static pages like:

```
www.myproject.com/signup
www.myproject.com/about
```

where would I put folders like that in our project tree? I tried putting them under war/, just beside projectname.html (like above), but they don't seem to be available there, I just get a 404 error,

Thanks

Comment: Yes, war/ is the correct place to put static files in. I don't see why this shouldn't work - are you sure your Java/HTTP server is working when you are trying to access these files?

Comment: Yes my dumb mistake, I had a Filter running which was messing this up, it works perfectly, sorry bout that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as pointed out by Igor Klimer, I had a Filter enabled which was messing up the routing.